# Increase random number probability swift

Tags: swift, probability, arc4random

I'm trying to make a game where the hero damage is generated randomly within a range but the more luck the hero has, the higher probability the hero will have to hit with the max damage number within that range.

I'm using a Double extension to make it easier on myself.

```
public extension Double {

  public static func random(lower: Double = 0, _ upper: Double = 100) -> Double {

    return (Double(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) * (upper - lower) + lower

}

//Assigning the random number to a constant
let heroDamage = Double.random(5, 15)
```

Let's say the hero has now an 80% of probability on getting the max damage(in this case 15), how would I approach this?, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Weighted Random is a common term for what you are trying to do.

Comment: GameplayKit has a protocol for randomisation. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKRandom_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/GKRandom

Comment: Thanks, I Appreciate the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given max damage probability of `pMaxDamage` (say, `pMaxDamage = 0.80`), one simple solution is to generate a random number, say `r`, in `[0,1]` and output:

- `maxDamage` if `r <= pMaxDamage`,
- a random damage in range `[minDamage, maxDamage]`, otherwise.

E.g.:

```
class Hero {
    let heroName: String
    let pMaxDamage: Double // probability to generate max damage

    init(heroName: String, pMaxDamage: Double) {
        self.heroName = heroName
        self.pMaxDamage = pMaxDamage
    }

    func generateDamage(minDamage minDamage: Double, maxDamage: Double) -> Double {
        let r = (Double(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)

        return r <= pMaxDamage ? maxDamage
            : round(100*((r-pMaxDamage)/(1-pMaxDamage)*(minDamage-maxDamage)+maxDamage))/100
    }
}
```

For the above implementation the `r-damage` (`r` uniform random number in `[0, 1]`) response curve looks as follows:

[image]

Example usage:

```
let myHero = Hero(heroName: "Foo", pMaxDamage: 0.80)
for _ in (1...10) {
    print("Slash! <\(myHero.generateDamage(minDamage: 5, maxDamage: 15)) damage>")
}
```

Example output:

```
Slash! <15.0 damage>
Slash! <12.68 damage>
Slash! <15.0 damage>
Slash! <15.0 damage>
Slash! <5.72 damage>
Slash! <15.0 damage>
Slash! <15.0 damage>
Slash! <15.0 damage>
Slash! <15.0 damage>
Slash! <15.0 damage>
```

---

If you want your damage values to only take integer values, an alternative solution would be roulette wheel selection with

- `pMaxDamage` probability of picking `maxDamage`,
- uniform `(1-pMaxDamage)/(numDamagePoints-1)` probability of picking any of the remaining `{minDamage, minDamage+1, ..., maxDamage-1}` damage values.

Comment: Thanks for your solution!, it's really what I was aiming for!

Comment: @extrablade Happy to help. I added an `r-damage` response curve to my answer, to ease presentation of how damage is generated w.r.t. the uniform random number `r`.

Comment: Thank-you. Really very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add a luck to the random function? Pure linear implementation here. You could use some advanced curves though.

```
private let MaxLuck = 1000.0
public extension Double {
    public static func random(lower: Double = 0, _ upper: Double = 100, luck: Double) -> Double {
        let weight = min(luck / MaxLuck, 1)
        return (Double(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) * weight * (upper - lower) + lower
    }
}
```

Comment: var heroDamage = Double.random(5, 35, luck: 0) //(always outputs 5, good

)
var heroDamage2 = Double.random(5, 35, luck: 1000) //(output random numbers?,i'm trying to make it 100% so it's always 35)

Comment: @extrablade Oh, I thought you still want some sort of randomness even when the hero is super lucky. LOL

Comment: If you want strict increasing of the damage along with the luck, then you don't need random. Just do `(35 - 5) * min(MaxLuck, (MaxLuck - luck)) + 5` and done!